# The use of the word terribilissimo in Latin?

Tags: latin

I was watching the anime `Black Butler` the other day when a song was played. I looked up the song to see what the lyrics were. I came across several sources that read the same and was sung in Latin. From the song `Si deus me relinquit`, all the sources I've come across has used the word `terribilissimo`. The full song is

```
Si deus me relinquit,
Ego deum relinquo.
Solus oppressus nigram clavem habere potest,
Omnias ianuas praecludo
Sic omnias precationes obsigno.
Sed
qui me defendet?
Ab me terribilissimo ipse.
```

The only problem I have is that I cannot find anything to reference `terribilissimo` in Latin. I'm aware that in Italian it means `most terrible`.

Perhaps it's a misheard lyric and it's really `terribile sim`, but to not be corrected at least once?

Can anyone tell me how one would get that word in Latin, if it exists, from `terribilis`?

Comment: If you rewrote it as *A me terribile sim ipse,* it could possibly be translated:"Let me be dreadfully by myself."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Meaning***
**Terribilis -e** *adj,*

> (Smith) [terreo] frightful, dreadful, terrible.
>   (Ainsworth) dreadful,
>   terrible, to be feared; awful.

Both Smith and Ainsworth give examples of the comparative "more terrible" to describe a) the Roman people,*terribilior,* b) events, *terribiliora*.

*Terribilissimus* is a regularly formed superlative, "most/ very terrible"
*terribilissimo* could be either Dative or Ablative sing m. or n.
Here after *a,ab* ="by" it is ablative.

> **Sed
>
>    qui me defendet?
>
>   Ab me terribilissimo ipse.**

But
 who will defend me ?
Myself from most terrifying me.

***Pronunciation & Stress***
from Thompson and Penn 1963 Jnr Latin Course 1963:

> Words of more than two syllables are accented on the last syllable
>   but one if that syllable is long, e.g. *soro'res,* sisters; but
>   otherwise on the last syllable but two, e.g. *do'minus;* lord; *fami'lia.* family;

[so the stress would fall on -iss- as in *Italian* 'bravissimo']

***Exceptions:*** 
In medieval verse  some multisyllabic words are given a second, and even a third, (light) stress.

Abelard (dactyls): [Penguin: *Latin Verse,* p195] *O Quanta Qualia*

> I'llic ex sa'bbato su'ccedet sa'bbatum,//
>   Pe'rpes laeti'tia **sa**'bati**za'n**ti-um, ...

The Archpoet (trochaics) [Penguin: *Latin Verse,* p206]

> Prae'sul di'screti'ssime, / ve'ni-a'm te pre'cor//
>   Mo'rte bo'na
>   mo'ri-or, / du'lce ne'ce ne'cor.// ...
>   Re's est a'rdu-i'ssima / vi'ncere' natu'ram//...

*Libre Vermeille,* (trochaics) in '[Cu'ncti si'mus co'ncane'ntes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYBMO0PsFcQ),'  *concanentes* and *karissime,* both tetra-syllabic, are stressed first and third.

Comment: Sorry, just a follow up question on pronunciation. Terribilis is pronounced `terˈri.bi.lis`. I'm guessing terribilissimo is pronounced `ter'ri.bi.lis.sim.o`, is that correct?

Comment: I don't think we know much about stress in Latin.

Comment: I tried looking for Latin Language on SE, but couldn't find one, which is why I originally asked here. Thanks anyways. I'll keep looking around.

Comment: @CodeMonkey  The Latin site is  not yet fully fledged: <area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75409/latin-language>  but I have edited my answer to illustrate stress in post-classical Latin verse.